# After migration of an old WP blog on my local web server I obtain white screen, why? is it a wp_options DB table problem?

Tags: installation, migration, localhost, options, local-installation

I am pretty new in WP (I came from Joomla) and I am finding some difficulties in the migration of an old WP website (made inWP 3.5) on my local web server.

I have performed the following operation:

1. I have put the website backup into a directory named **blog** into my Apache **www** directory on my Ubuntu local system.
2. Then I have put the database backup on my MySql local server
3. Finally I have change the values in the **wp-config.php** file to use my local DB

The problem is that when I try to open the URL:

```
http://localhost/blog/
```

to see the website I see noting (a white screen)

Inside the **wp-config.php** I have activated the debug mode by the line:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

and I have no errors, so I think that this is not a DB problem.

Inside the Apache error log file (**/var/log/apache2/error.log**) I found that the following errors occurs:

```
[Fri Jan 10 22:04:50 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 10 22:05:08 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:05:08 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:37 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:37 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:38 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:38 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:39 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:39 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:40 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:40 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
```

Reading online it seems to me that I also have to change the values of the **home** and **siteurl** fields into the **wp_options** database table (they contained references to the site on the old server), so I have change it with these values:

- **home**: `http://localhost/blog`
- **siteurl**: `http://localhost/blog`

But the problem persist (I always see a white screen).

I think that maybe the problem could be that these value are wrong, or maybe I have change some other values? Or maybe I also create a specific **.htacces** file into my **blog** directory? (now I have no **.htaccess** file)

Do you have some idea about how to solve this problem?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: *require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12*. Exist that file?

Comment: yes , it exist !!!

Comment: I just can recommend you to transfer the backup again (site folder and database.sql) via FTP and try again from scratch.